# Redux-Form on input blur makes another input blank

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm having a strange redux-form 7.3.0 bug or error. I created the following gif screencast in order to explain it, but briefly, as the title suggests, when i leave an input with either click on another input or tab key, the redux-form blur event is dispatched and another input is blanked!! See below:

[image: Screencast showing the bug] 
As you can see, the first time that i enter the view it doesn't happen. But after going back and reentering... the bug appears! I have no clue of why. 
I have a lead, i noticed that after blur event is dispatched on input, the next state in the store, in the redux-form reducer 'form', that is redux-form handled, the field name goes missing in the prop values, which is an immutable map i think. In previous state, it has both (email and name as seen in the screencast).

If need to know... i'm using immutable library and immutable reducer initial states (not top level, but per-reducer basis).

See here the screenshot for both previous and nextState during redux-form/blur event:

prevState:
[image: redux-form blur prevState]

nextState:
[image: redux-form blur nextState]

Hope this info helps to resolve the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the glitch. It was because i was not importing the immutable version of the redux-form reducer!!!

```
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form/immutable'
```